# Ubuntu 18.04, RTX 4090 wired connection not found problem

Tags: connection, wired

I have msi MAG B760M MORTAR and I installed ubuntu 18.04. My GPU is rtx 4090.My problem is that wired connection is not found. how can I solve my problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNeIk.jpg)

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support